# CSS: how to dynamically resize img element without affecting surrounding textflow

Tags: css, angular, css-transitions, image-resizing

I have an Angular component displaying an image surrounded by text. The text wraps around the image. When I click the image, it expands through css `transition: width 1s ease-in-out`. Problem is, the html flow is affected so the text sourrounding the image is wrapped and the containng box resizes to accomodate the resized image.

I want *only* the image to be resized and the rest - text, box - should remain as is.

When I apply `position:absolute` to the image, that is exactly what happens but then the text doesn't float around the image anymore.

Below 2 images - one of image in text box, 2nd of resized image.

[image: Image with text]

[image: Expanded image with text and containing box resized]

The resizing is done in the image component:

image.component.ts

```
@Component({
    selector: 'lib-image[imageUrl]',
    templateUrl: './image.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./image.component.scss'],
})
export class ImageComponent {
    @Input() imageUrl!: string;
    @Input() alt: string = '';
    @Input() caption: string = '';
    @Input() expand: boolean = false;

    public expanded: boolean = false;
    public containerClass: string = 'container';
    public imageClass: string = 'image__thumbnail';

    ngOnInit() {
        this.imageClass += this.expand ? ' image--cursorPointer' : '';
    }

    expandImage() {
        if (this.expand) {
            this.expanded = !this.expanded;
            this.containerClass = this.expanded ? 'container__expanded' : 'container';
            this.imageClass = this.expanded ? 'image__expanded' : 'image__thumbnail';
            this.imageClass += ' image--cursorPointer';
        }
    }
}
```

image.component.html

```
<div [ngClass]="containerClass">
    <img
        [src]="imageUrl"
        [alt]="alt"
        [title]="alt"
        [ngClass]="imageClass"
        (click)="expandImage()"
    />

    <figure class="image__figure">
        {{ caption }}
    </figure>
</div>
```

image.component.scss

```
.container,
.container__expanded {
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    transition: width 1s ease-in-out;
    width: 9rem;

    &.container__expanded {
        width: 45rem;
    }
}

.image__expanded,
.image__thumbnail {
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 0 #ccc;
    margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
    transition: width 1s ease-in-out;
    width: 9rem;
}

.image__expanded {
    width: 45rem;
}

.image__figure {
    font-style: italic;
    color: #333;
    margin: 0;
    width: max-content;
}

.image--cursorPointer {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Instead of using width, you can try transform: scaleX(2) and animate transform..

Comment: That doesn't solve my problem - width or scaleX, they both disrupt the flow of the text and resize the bounding box when the image is transformed.

Comment: Do you know the width and height of the image? Than you could create a <div> with fixed width and height that contains the image . The <div> can be display: block and the image can have position: absolute.

Comment: I created a little demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dedidc?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: That looks good indeed... text doesn't reflow when image resizes. Thanks!

Comment: @Marc Not trying to be pedantic but "they both disrupt the flow of the text and resize the bounding box when the image is transformed" - is not correct I think: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fjjlbn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css - which makes this the most clean and simple I guess? Or are you seeing something else?